# EOF record missing in file1 during file comparison in cobol

Tags: file, record, matching, eof, cobol

Hi I have written cobol file comparison program .In that both input1 and input2 have duplicates.
I got all the keys in output file and I am missing eof-input1 record in output.as I know I have handle the EOF condition correcly..
My scenario is I have to compare file1 and file2.
If file1=file2
Need to move input 1 record to output after performing some process.
Else
If file1>file2
need to move file1 record to output after performing some process.

In main para..
I did process until end-of-input1.
Please suggest some solution to get my last input1 record.

I didn't use any temp variable to move my IP data and for processing...

Thank you!!

Comment: Sow us what you have done sofr: Show the code you have (formatted as ˋcodeˋ) and show input and output.

Answer (score 0):

```
               Mainpara.
                    Read file1.
                    Read file2.
                     Process para until end of input1.
                     Close files.
                  
             Process para.

                      If  in1>in2 
                           Perform read file2 until eof2 or in2>=in1
                       End-if.
               If eof2 = 'N'
                    If In2=in1
                         Some process
                     End-if
                   If  In2 >in1
                         Some process
                    End-if
              Else
                  Moves
              End
```

Ip1: 111133445
Ip1:11347
Test op: 134
Required op: 1345

Comment: I am not able put in comment so answered to my own Q's.pls chk.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question. It is the code belonging to your question. Please **edit** your question and insert the code and the sample input 1 & 2 *formatted as `code`, then delete this answer.

Comment: Can you please make sure your question text and the source code match. E.g. in the text you wrote *if file1 > file2...* but the code shows *In2 > In1* which is not the same. I don't understand the text below the code (*lp1:1112245....).